# Compile-time check of conversion from a string?

Tags: c++, compile-time, error-detection

Let's have a class `Foo` which defines a conversion constructor from a string. Depending on the contents of the string, this constructor can succeed (an instance of `Foo` is created) or fail (an exception is thrown):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const char* s)
    {
        if (<format of s is valid>)
            <create Foo, based on the contents of s>;
        else
            <throw an exception>;
    }

[...]
};
```

We also have `operator==()` for comparing a `Foo` and a string:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& foo1, const char* s)
{
    // s is converted to a Foo, after which the two instances of Foo are compared
}
```

Client code presumably calls the comparison operator most often with valid string literals:

```
if (myFoo == "<some valid string literal for building a Foo>") // A - normal case
    [...]
```

but sometimes it may call the comparison operator with an invalid string literal (programmer's mistake):

```
if (myFoo == "<some invalid string literal for building a Foo>") // B - abnormal case, throws an exception
    [...]
```

Is there a way to detect case B at compile-time instead of run-time? (I hope there is, but fear there isn't...)

Note: The validity of the string could be checked, for example, with a regular expression.

Comment: What exactly is the format of a valid string?  Have you considered possibly using a compile-time regular expression checker, if the format can be specified using a regular expression?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, the validity of the string could be checked with a regular expression (just added a note to my question). Can compile-time regex checkers be used in C++14?

Comment: Might not be possible, unless you're willing to wrap your strings in a macro, or a template like `foo<"...">` (needs C++20), or UDL `"..."_foo` (requires non-standard extension supported by GCC & Clang, but not MSVC).

Comment: @user1387866 -- I see there is [one here](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions), but I don't think it will support anything below C++17.